# Let K be the number of ways 16 students can be arranged around a square table having 4 seats on each side.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**Question:**

> Let $K$ be the number of ways $16$ students can be arranged around a square table having $4$ seats on each side.
> If $K = a(b!)$ with $b$ is maximum, find value of $a + b$.

**My method:**

> I took $4$ members as a string, and I got $4$ strings and then I can arrange them in $3!$ ways. So total arrangements= $3!(4!\cdot4!\cdot4!\cdot4!)$ 
> As I can arrange $4$ members in $4!$ ways and then fundamental rule of multiplication.

Comment: Are rotations of the table distinct?

Comment: Are the seats numbered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **why your method is wrong**:
You are not considering the cases where a person from $1$ string can sit on the same side with the person from another string (and their permutations of course).

Alternatively, **you could do the following**:
Let's look at the options for the $1^{st}$ person to be seated. 
For that person all the sides are same. But once he/she selects/decides to sit on a particular side then he/she has $4$ choices: *leftmost, mid-left, mid-right, rightmost*. 
Now the remaining $15$ people can be seated in $15!$ ways.

So the total number of ways of arranging students: $4(15!)=K$

We know that $b$ can't be $16$ so $15$ is the maximum value it can take.
So, $a+b=19.$

Comment: Very thanks bro!!

Answer (score 3):

We know that had they been seated in an unnumbered circle, the number of arrangements $=\frac{16!}{16}$ because there are $16$ possible indistinguishable rotations.

For a square, there are $4$ possible indistinguishable rotations,
thus # of arrangements = $\frac{16!}{4} = 4\cdot15!\implies a+b = 19$

Answer (score 1):

Since one is counting orbits of arrangements, for the cyclic group of order$~4$ that rotates the arrangements around the table, you can use Burnside's lemma, which states that the number of orbits is the average over the group of the number of arrangements fixed by the symmetry. Since no arrangement has any non-trivial symmetry at all, we get all $16!$ arrangements fixed by the identity, and none by any other symmetry. The number of orbits it therefore the average over the $4$ outcomes, which is $\frac{16!+0+0+0}4 = 4\times15!$.